# How to use tcdl:ComponentPresentation tag inside of tcdl:Link?

Tags: dynamic-linking, tcdl

I'd like to implement label as dynamic component presentation.
(I mean "label" as text which is used in whole WEB site, like "see more" on link button.)
And I want to use TCDL tag, because it works both of .NET and Java enviroment.

I created a schema which has only one text field, and input label text on a component which is based on the schema.
Then I created a dynamic component template which output the label text.
On component template DWT, I write tcdl:ComponentPresentation tag to output label, then it works fine.

But problem occurs when using dynamic linking(component link).
To implement dynamic linking, I write tcdl:Link tag, and tcdl:ComponentPresentation tag inside of it to output label text.
But label is not displayed on WEB page, because tridion:ComponentPresentation tag is in LinkText attribute of tridion:ComponentLink tag as text on published ASPX page.

DWT:

```
<tcdl:Link type="Component" origin="tcm:0-0-0" destination="@@LinkedComponentID@@" templateURI="tcm:0-0-0">
<tcdl:ComponentPresentation type="Dynamic" PageURI="@@PageID@@" ComponentURI="@@LabelComponentID@@" TemplateURI="@@LabelComponentTemplateID@@" />
</tcdl:Link>
```

Published ASPX page:

```
<tridion:ComponentLink runat="server" PageURI="tcm:0-0-0" ComponentURI="tcm:21-556" TemplateURI="tcm:0-0-0" AddAnchor="false" 
LinkText="&lt;tridion:ComponentPresentation runat=&#34;server&#34; PageURI=&#34;tcm:21-1136-64&#34; ComponentURI=&#34;tcm:21-1083&#34; TemplateURI=&#34;tcm:21-1082-32&#34;/&gt;" />
```

I want to output following code on published ASPX page.

```
<tridion:ComponentLink runat="server" PageURI="tcm:0-0-0" ComponentURI="tcm:21-556" TemplateURI="tcm:0-0-0" AddAnchor="false" >
<tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:21-1136-64" ComponentURI="tcm:21-1083" TemplateURI="tcm:21-1082-32"/>
</tridion:ComponentLink>
```

Is it possible to use tcdl:ComponentPresentation tag inside of tcdl:Link tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the Deployer does not resolve `tcdl` tags inside out, which means it does not support nested tags unfortunately.

However when looking at your construct I would say that is sounds rather expensive to use a Dynamic Component Presentation, just for a single label value.

I would personally create a labels Component and publish that as a resource bundle with a set of key, value pairs. Then create something in your ASPX page to read that label from the resource bundle.